# Simple Vue 3 project with TypeScript cannot resolve ts dependencies

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

First let me provide a link to the git repository: https://github.com/kbottner/vue3ts

Very simple Vue3 project made from the vue-cli that has TypeScript enabled. If you review the commits you will see that one simple change (the addition of a ts file to be included in a vue file) causes the project to no longer function.

If I execute `npm run build`

I receive the following output:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ../composables/test.js in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
```

If I change it to an absolute path I get a similar albeit slightly different response:

```
This dependency was not found:

* @/composables/test.js in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
```

I have searched far and wide but have not be able to resolve the issue. I believe it has something to do with how Typescript is integrated but honestly am at a loss for how to resolve. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you're trying to import is `test.ts`, but you're importing it as `test.js`, which does not exist.

You don't need to specify the extension here. Just using `import { testMe } from '@/composables/test'` is fine.

Comment: That works perfectly, so simple. Thanks for the quick response.